# Change Statistic Labels in PROC MEANS (like KEYLABEL in PROC TABULATE)

Tags: sas

I know I can use the command KEYLABEL in PROC TABULATE to specify a custom label for the statistic names i.e:

KEYLABEL N = ' '  ALL = "Total" PCTN = "Percent" SUM = "Total";

It doesn't work with PROC MEANS. Is there an equivalent command? Can I use a workaround to do this? I'm running the SAS program and generating the Latex markeup automatically from that, so I need to change the names of the N, SUM, MEAN, MEDIAN, MIN, MAX columns reported in the PROC MEANS command if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, I highly recommend asking on the SAS Listserv (sas-l@listserv.uga.edu).  One of the users is highly skilled at *tex output and may well have encountered this in the past.  I'll look around at SUGI papers he's written and see if any of them seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the automatic variable labels in PROC MEANS to something custom, unfortunately.  You can label the variable:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
var age;
label age="Child's Age";
class name;
output out=classmean sum=;
run;
```

You can use AUTOLABEL to automatically append (default) labels:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
var age;
label age="Child's Age";
class name;
output out=classmean sum= n= /autoname autolabel;
run;
```

But I don't think you can control it further than that.  The easiest solution I can imagine is writing a macro to do it using PROC DATASETS [taking the known variable names and assigning them labels based on those names].  I don't know what you need to make them, but it's not terribly difficult to do.  Something like this (the proc sql in particular will vary significantly based on your program).

```
%macro relabel(var=);
label &var._n = "&var. Count";
*... more of these ...;
%mend relabel;

proc sql;
select cats('%relabel(var=',name,')') into :rellist separated by ' ' 
  from dictionary.columns
  where memname='MYDATASET' and libname='WORK' and *criteria to determine in proc means*;
quit;
proc datasets;
&rellist.
quit;
```